# Dealing with a chat user who does not understand social cues

Tags: support, chat, banning

I don't like to put the subject on an open view like this but as the issue has been raised before, I have to speak about it.

I'm one of the owner of a [room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql), we frequently have people who are coming and asking for questions.

From time to time, we have a user who comes and start behaving like a child, not respecting our times and behaving aggressively or just moralizing us.

I've told him before but he persists.

- Would calling a mod be a good step in these situations?
- Should we ban him (even though we are trying to be welcoming)?

Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S.: I do not want to put the transcript, at least not before I have some feedback from the community at large.

Comment: is it true that in SQL room folks are required to chat in uppercase?

Comment: hi @gnat, not that I'm aware of ... :)

Comment: I swear that room has been deserted every time I've visited in the last 5 years.

Comment: @canon we are a merry bunch now. come mate

Comment: @gnat I just got your joke ... -_- #lmao

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "not respecting our times"? Like, he'll show up at (your local) 0200 and expect instant responses from you, then throw a tantrum when it totally reasonable takes you six to eight hours to get back to him? Or something else that I can't think of because I'm dumb?

Comment: Hi @QPaysTaxes, forget about asking questions and expect instant responses, just throwing a tantrum for reasons only known to that person and beg us to do not do things like having a beer, after we shared with him that we were enjoying a beer from time to time.

Comment: @AndyK Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can kick-mute the user: [Impose a re-entry delay on users kicked out of a chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229905/impose-a-re-entry-delay-on-users-kicked-out-of-a-chat-room/239226#239226)

The first kick will last only one minute, which may be enough for the user to understand they need to change their behaviour. Subsequent kicks will increase the time.

> The short story is: room owners can kick abusive users, who will then be banned from re-entering the room for a certain time.
>
> [...]
>
> If this is the first time the user is kicked anywhere (i.e., not necessarily in the same room) in the last 24 hours, the ban will last one minute. If it is the second time, the ban will last five minutes.
>
> If it is the third or more time the user has been kicked within 24 hours, the ban will last for 30 minutes. In addition, the user is automatically banned from creating new rooms and from sending invites. This automatic ban does not expire and can only be removed by a moderator. Moderators can also remove the kick-ban before it expires.

There's also an extensive guide available on MSE: [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat)